# How to connect to the pi over serial

Tags: serial, serial-console

So I am trying to connect to my pi over serial. I have never used serial, so I hope what I have is fine. I can't order anything new. I have a USB to serial adapter (RS232 I think, you can check the picture below) and an RS232(i think) connector. I would like to connect the USB connector to my PC(windows or Linux) and the other connector to my pi, and then access the terminal over serial. I have a monitor to set stuff up, and I have PuTTY. I am using a pi 3 running the latest stretch lite image.
[image: USB adapter]

[image: serial connector]

Comment: I also have an adapter as both connectors are male I think

Comment: Raspberry Pi is a 3,3volt serial and you have probably higher voltage on your USB-Serial converter. And with your comment "Not anything new" then it's impossible to solve with what you have!

Comment: It almost sounds like SSH-ing in or running a virtual desktop would be better here. Is there a particular reason you're wanting to Serial?

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, you have bought the wrong device. What you need is a USB to serial device with 3.3V compatible outputs. There are hundreds of posts on connecting these.

**There is NO WAY to connect RS232 to the Pi** (except with a RS232 to 3.3V "TTL" adapter).

You could use the device you have in the Pi USB port to connect to a "RS232" interface on a PC (if you can find one - most PC manufactured in the last 10 years don't).
You then need to configure the Pi to use the resultant serial port (something like `/dev/ttyUSB0`) as a console.

To do this you need to check that the device you have has a driver supported by the Pi and reconfigure the Pi to use this as console - this is not a task for a beginner, but if you post details you may get help.

Answer (score -1):

> **WARNING - Do NOT do this on the Pi** This may be OK for a RS232 device - which the Pi is **NOT**. RS232 is ±15V, although most dongles use 0-5V neither is compatible with the 3.3V logic of the Pi. Even with level converters it will not work because RS232 polarity is reversed.

**Use with caution**

I'm not sure if it works but I have done it on machines and it works well didn't get the need to try it on pi
As you said that you don't encourage new items 
[image: dothe following connection to one of the UART pins on Rapi GPIO]

Don't forget to common the ground and look for com port in device manager 
when if the device appears , then check for baud rate and use putty